# Bash MD5checksum loop

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, md5sum

Each file has it's md5 checksum created, before my script looks at it, so these .md5 files already exist (They are made right after the files are tard). I'm checking to make sure nobody has changed any of the files, from the time they are created, to the time I look at it.

What i'm trying to do is loop through this list, find all .md5 checksums, and compare them with the md5 checksum of the actual file.

Example: This is what my directory looks like...

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 awiles awiles  209904416 Nov 29 17:53 590465-1_v1.200.tar.gz*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 awiles awiles         57 Nov 29 17:53 590465-1_v1.200.tar.gz.md5*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 awiles awiles    1341076 Nov 29 17:53 590466-1_v1.320.tar.gz*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 awiles awiles         57 Nov 29 17:53 590466-1_v1.320.tar.gz.md5*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 awiles awiles  214723375 Nov 29 18:03 590467-1_v2.700.tar.gz*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 awiles awiles         57 Nov 29 18:03 590467-1_v2.700.tar.gz.md5*
-r-xr-xr-x 1 awiles awiles 2482573113 Nov 29 18:02 590468-1_v1.020.tar.gz*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 awiles awiles         46 Nov 29 18:02 590468-1_v1.020.tar.gz.md5*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 awiles awiles   28043339 Nov 29 17:53 590505-1_v1.040.tar.gz*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 awiles awiles         57 Nov 29 17:53 590505-1_v1.040.tar.gz.md5*
```

My current bash code...

```
for f in $DIR/*
do
  if [[ $f == *".md5" ]] ; then
      md5sum -c $f
  fi
done
```

I'm getting the following errors...

```
md5sum: 590465-1_v1.200.tar.gz: No such file or directory
590465-1_v1.200.tar.gz: FAILED open or read
md5sum: WARNING: 1 listed file could not be read
```

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: `md5sum` is trying to read the filenames from the current directory. You can `cd` to the dir first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the output of `md5sum`, it expects `590465-1_v1.200.tar.gz` to be in the current directory. Your script will only work when `DIR` is `.`.
If that's not the case, then you should `cd` to `$DIR` first, for example like this:

```
(
cd "$DIR" && for f in *
do
  if [[ $f == *".md5" ]] ; then
      md5sum -c $f
  fi
done
)
```

I wrapped it in `(...)` so that you don't have to remember to `cd "$OLDPWD"` when you are done. (Using `cd` within scripts often leads to strange bugs due to oversight.)

Comment: Or simpler `(cd "$DIR" && for f in *.md5; do md5sum -c "$f"; done)`

Answer (score -1):

Simple way:

`ls -1 *.md5 |while read line; do cat $line ; done|md5sum -c`

Some similar way:

`md5sum * > checklist.chk` # generates a list of checksums for any file that matches *

`md5sum -c checklist.chk` # runs through the list to check them